# Passing lists of initialized components as props

Tags: reactjs

Note: the question has been fully re-written, which may render some comments irrelevant.

I am trying to write a component (e.g. a form) that combines sub-components of different kinds (e.g. inputs of various types). The component does not know in advance how many sub-components of each kind it will need to display. In addition, each kind of sub-component will need to be displayed with its own style.

For example, let's define two classes for two kinds of sub-components:

```css
.prim-class {
  color: blue;
}

.sec-class {
  color: green;
}
```

Here is a solution using function calls that works ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-surf-6jj9t?file=/src/App.js:24-377)):

```
const prim = (text) => <h1>{text}</h1>;

const sec = (text) => <h2>{text}</h2>;

const comp = (prims, secs) => (
  <>
    <div className="prim-class">{prims}</div>
    <div className="sec-class">{secs}</div>
  </>
);

export default function App() {
  return <div>{comp([prim("AA"), prim("BB")], [sec("CC")])}</div>;
}
```

This produces the expected result:

[image]

As I understand, using function calls as above is not the React way of doing things (please correct me if I am wrong here). I am now trying to use the component style instead of the functional one ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-hooks-8h2kh?file=/src/App.js)):

```
const prim = ({ text }) => <h1>{text}</h1>;

const sec = ({ text }) => <h2>{text}</h2>;

const comp = ({ prims, secs }) => (
  <>
    <div className="prim-class">{prims}</div>
    <div className="sec-class">{secs}</div>
  </>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <comp
        prims={[<prim text="AA" />, <prim text="BB" />]}
        secs={[<sec text="CC" />]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The result is empty page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually facing any error/problem with your code? Instead of asking others to guess what's wrong in your code, it would be better to explain your problem. Also, I think it would be better to pass the components to `authForm` as children and access them inside the `authForm` component using `props.children`  object.

Comment: `props.children` will be an object containing the components in the order in which you nested them inside the `authForm` component. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Codesandbox demo or demo created using stack snippets option on stackoverflow question editor toolbar would make it easy to debug your code.

Comment: I think you are complicating a simple task. You could just do `<div>{ props.children }</div>` inside the `authForm` component and nest the components inside the `authForm` component in any way you want. This will work even if you create the form children components dynamically.

Comment: @Yousaf I have fully re-written the question using the minimal example and deleted my comments.

Comment: If you look at the console in the demo you shared (example with empty page), there's a warning that React component names should start with uppercase letters. If you capitalize the first letter of `comp`, `prim`, and `sec`, your demo will work as expected. However, [here's an alternative solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-star-32ym3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Yousaf Please post this as a reply, so I can accept it.